# MS SQL Server split words on spaces but only when not in double-quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following function in SQL I used to take a varchar "query" string from a search page on my website. It splits the String parameters into temp table with a list of all words in that query. However I would like to incorporate the ability for users to search for phrases by enclosing words in quotes. So that a phase would basically be considered one word in my returned temp table.
So basically the way it works now if you search "Gold TV" 4K it would return something like

- "Gold
- TV"
- 4K

And I would like it to return

- Gold TV
- 4K

I haven't been able to get the logic right, here is my current function. Or if there is a much better way to do this let me know.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[querySplit](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))     
as     
begin     
declare @idx int     
declare @slice varchar(8000)     

select @idx = 1     
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return     

while @idx!= 0     
begin     
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)     
    if @idx!=0     
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)     
    else     
        set @slice = @String     

    if(len(@slice)>0)
        insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)     

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)     
    if len(@String) = 0 break     
end 
return     
end
```

Comment: What's your SQL Server version? `(select @@version)`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014  - 12.0.6372.1 (X64)

Comment: This is much easier in a procedural language, TSQL really isn't good at this sort of thing. Do it in your client app, and pass in a Table Valued Parameter of different strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the use of a helper function and a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Max "Gold TV" 4K Ultra'

Select Parsed = coalesce(B.RetVal,replace(A.RetVal,'"','')) 
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](replace(replace(' '+@S+' ',' "','|"'),'" ','"|'),'|') A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (case when A.RetVal like '%"%' then null else A.RetVal end,' ') B
 Where B.RetVal is not null
    or charindex('"',A.RetVal)>0
 Order By A.RetSeq,B.RetSeq
```

**Results**

```
Parsed
Max
Gold TV
4K
Ultra
```

Since you are on 2014, here is my split/parse function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
          ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

Comment: @lptr Curious.  I'll take a peek

Comment: @lptr A small tweak to the WHERE resolved the duplicate spaces.   The 200K spaces seems unrealistic.   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5200694711d3c42b685c16a4b6dfc36a

Answer (score 1):

Here's your UDF with a few tweaks.

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[querySplit] (
>  @String VARCHAR(8000),
>  @Delimiter CHAR(1)
> )
> RETURNS @Tbl TABLE (items VARCHAR(8000))
> WITH SCHEMABINDING
> AS
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE @idx INT;
>   DECLARE @slice VARCHAR(8000);
>   
>   SET @idx = 1;
>   IF LEN(@String)<1 OR @String IS NULL RETURN;
>   
>   WHILE @idx != 0
>   BEGIN
>   
>     IF LEFT(@String,1) = '"'
>     BEGIN
>       SET @String = STUFF(@String, 1, 1, '');
>       SET @idx = CHARINDEX('"', @String, 2);
>     END
>     ELSE 
>       SET @idx = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String);
>     
>     IF @idx != 0
>         SET @slice = LEFT(@String, @idx-1);
>     ELSE
>         SET @slice = @String;
>     
>     IF (LEN(@slice)>0)
>       INSERT INTO @Tbl (Items) VALUES (@slice);
>     
>     SET @String = RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @idx);
>     IF LEN(@String) = 0 break;
>   END
>   RETURN;
> END
> ```

> ```
> select quotename(items)
> from dbo.querySplit('"Diamond 3D Goggles" "5 inch×2"', ' ')
> ```

> | (No column name) |
> | --- |
> | [Diamond 3D Goggles] |
> | [5 inch×2] |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=16410341f4b03ec0186dcbdfb1fa05fd)*