# How to select specific comma delimiters and split the string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these values in a column:

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | a,b,(alpha,beta),c |
| two | three | a,(alpha,beta),c,d |

I want to split the string in to serve columns where there is comma, but I want to ignore such commas where the comma actually is not separating the values.

I tried split string in SQL Server but it's separating from each comma which is not the task here. Here's the expected output, is this achievable?

| left | center | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | a | b | (alpha,beta) | c |
| One | Two | a | (brad,pitt) | c | d |

Comment: I really recommend fixing your design here. That is the *real* solution. Seems like you potentionially need *3* tables here.

Comment: Try making your own Split function https://sqlsunday.com/2022/04/22/string_split-for-quoted-names/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS SQL Server split words on spaces but only when not in double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70545673/ms-sql-server-split-words-on-spaces-but-only-when-not-in-double-quotes)

Comment: And when we say "fix" the design, we say that because this schema design really is **broken**.

Comment: If there's any valid reason to store multiple values in a field, use something *supported* by SQL Server, like JSON or XML. There's no way to handle this with string splitting. You could try converting those strings to JSON by replacing `,(` with `",["`, `),` with `"],"`, commas with `","` and surround the entire string with `[]`. After that you could use eg `JSON_VALUE(that_json,'$.[3]')` to access specific items.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in SQL Server 2022+ or Azure you can get crafty with  [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) chaining it with CROSS APPLY

```
CREATE TABLE test (lft varchar(10), center varchar(10), rght varchar(30));
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('One','Two','a,(alha,bea),b,(alpha,beta),c,(alpa,bet)');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('two','three','a,(alpha,beta),c,d');

SELECT DISTINCT 
 test.lft, 
 test.center, 
 CASE WHEN ca.value like ca2.value + '%)%' THEN '(' + ca2.value + ')' ELSE ca3.value END AS rght_split,
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY test.lft, test.center ORDER BY ca.ordinal, ca2.ordinal, CASE WHEN ca.value not like ca2.value + '%' THEN ca3.ordinal ELSE 0 END) as rn
FROM test 
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(rght, '(', 1) as ca
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ca.value, ')', 1) as ca2
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ca2.value, ',', 1) as ca3
WHERE ca3.value <> '' 
ORDER BY lft, center, rn


+-----+--------+--------------+----+
| lft | center |  rght_split  | rn |
+-----+--------+--------------+----+
| One | Two    | a            |  1 |
| One | Two    | (alha,bea)   |  2 |
| One | Two    | b            |  3 |
| One | Two    | (alpha,beta) |  4 |
| One | Two    | c            |  5 |
| One | Two    | (alpa,bet)   |  6 |
| two | three  | a            |  1 |
| two | three  | (alpha,beta) |  2 |
| two | three  | c            |  3 |
| two | three  | d            |  4 |
+-----+--------+--------------+----+
```

This will perform the splitting while honoring the parentheticals. What is also nice is that we preserve the ordering and produce a row number (`rn`) that can drive the pivot function.

Tossing this into the pivot function:

```
SELECT lft, center, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]
FROM 
  (  
   SELECT DISTINCT 
     test.lft, 
     test.center, 
     CASE WHEN ca.value like ca2.value + '%)%' THEN '(' + ca2.value + ')' ELSE ca3.value END AS rght_split,
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY test.lft, test.center ORDER BY ca.ordinal, ca2.ordinal, CASE WHEN ca.value not like ca2.value + '%' THEN ca3.ordinal ELSE 0 END) as rn
   FROM test 
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(rght, '(', 1) as ca
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ca.value, ')', 1) as ca2
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ca2.value, ',', 1) as ca3
   WHERE ca3.value <> '' 
  )dt
PIVOT (MAX(rght_split) FOR rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) as pt
ORDER BY lft, center

+-----+--------+---+--------------+---+--------------+------+------------+
| lft | center | 1 |      2       | 3 |      4       |  5   |     6      |
+-----+--------+---+--------------+---+--------------+------+------------+
| One | Two    | a | (alha,bea)   | b | (alpha,beta) | c    | (alpa,bet) |
| two | three  | a | (alpha,beta) | c | d            | null | null       |
+-----+--------+---+--------------+---+--------------+------+------------+
```

Lastly, as others have noted, if you can "fix" this schema to not store multiple values in the same column, that would be best. You'll find that this string splitting is not super speedy, so removing that step from your pivot would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution based on *tokenization* via SQL Server's XML and XQuery functionality.

Notable points:

- 1st `CROSS APPLY` is tokenizing input string as XML.
- 2nd `CROSS APPLY` is "fixing" XML by composing a desired structure.
- XQuery `.value()` method is retrieving tokens based on their position for the c1 - c4 columns.

For example, the first row XML will be as follows:

```
<r>a</r>
<r>b</r>
<r>(alpha,beta)</r>
<r>c</r>
```

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, _left VARCHAR(10), _center VARCHAR(10), tokens NVARCHAR(256));
INSERT @tbl (_left, _center,tokens) VALUES
('One', 'Two', N'a,b,(alpha,beta),c'),
('Two', 'Three', N'a,(alpha,beta),c,d');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT t.* --, c, x   -- uncomment just to see
    , x.value('(/r[1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS c1
    , x.value('(/r[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS c2
    , x.value('(/r[3]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS c3
    , x.value('(/r[4]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS c4
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.query('
        for $x in /root/r
        let $pos := count(root/r[. << $x]) + 1
        return if (substring($x,1,1) eq "(") then element r {concat(string($x), ",", string((/root/r[$pos + 1])[1]))}
            else if (substring($x, string-length($x),1) eq ")") then ()
            else $x
    ')) AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

| id | _left | _center | tokens | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | One | Two | a,b,(alpha,beta),c | a | b | (alpha,beta) | c |
| 2 | Two | Three | a,(alpha,beta),c,d | a | (alpha,beta) | c | d |